# setting HttpContext.Current.User throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-4.5

This is a WCF Oneway operation. HttpContext.Current.User is cleared in those operations, that is the reason I added a behavior that saves the User before it is cleared. Later I want to re-set the HttpContext.Current.User with the value I saved but I'm getting an exception:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = (RolePrincipal)userThatWasSavedBefore;

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.HttpContext.SetPrincipalNoDemand(IPrincipal principal, Boolean needToSetNativePrincipal)
at System.Web.HttpContext.set_User(IPrincipal value)
at (My Function)
```

Why can't I set the user? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't set it is most likely that the request has finished.  Setting the User property results in ASP.NET trying to call back into per-request data structures, and if these data structures have been released then the resulting behavior is undefined.

For one-way operations, WCF invokes application code while simultaneously telling ASP.NET not to wait for the application code to finish and to just complete the request immediately.  For this reason is it strongly recommended that you don't access HttpContext from a one-way operation.

Comment: I suspect this is the case. Meanwhile I'll wait to see if there are some other relevant comments.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. However, in my case, the method is being called from SignalR Hub. Any Idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @UmairM did you solve? i have the same problem inside a SignalR Hub (AuthorizeAttribute) thanks

Comment: I had to change my implementation to work around this, so I ended up dropping the call altogether as most of my code was "badly architectured"

Answer (score 0):

Clearly some object in the line throwing the exception is null.

Check whether you have a current HttpContext, that is, I suspect HttpContext.Current is null.

Comment: are you sure HttpContext.Current is not null?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I can see "null" on the User in debugger and an instance on the Current.

Answer (score 0):

The call stack shows an [instance method of HttpContext](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpContext.cs,71e001c3e3531f26,references) is executed.

In other words - HttpContext is there, the exception is provoked by something else - a missing NulRef check likely for _notificationContext.

The [NotificationContext](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpContext.cs,b19ada8ad272b1a3,references) is internal and unset only by [OnRequestNotificationCompletionHelper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRuntime.cs,2080) as I write.

Exception scenario seem to look like:

- Some work is to be done async - does not block/prevent a request from being completed
- Request processing is finished
- Your worker item sets HttpContext.User for the finished request

This looks like a framework bug :(

Answer (score -1):

This problem is either because some object in these classes is null (such as HttpContext.Current)

OR

The user which you are passing there (and you saved before) is actually pointing to `null`. As you can see from stack trace, this is very likely the case, because the exception is thrown by `System.Web.HttpContext.set_User(IPrincipal value)`

User is actually not a variable, but a property. And changing it to another value is calling a function, that throws this exception in case new value for user is `null`.

In order to find out what is causing this problem I recommend you to set a breakpoint to the line which is throwing the exception and check if any part of that line isn't pointing to `null`

crash proof alternative could be:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null && userThatWasSavedBefore != null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.User = (RolePrincipal)userThatWasSavedBefore;
}
```

Comment: Current and userThatWasSavedBefore are valid instances , I can see the username and other members in the debugger..